# Why is there extra space in this text and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: css, unicode

Consider these two chunks of "confusables" Unicode text (in snippet).

The first one has (two) extra line breaks or extra space of some kind in it and looks awful,  while the second one displays quite nicely.  I've tried all the `white-space` CSS options but none have any effect on the empty space. (Pasting the same text into Notepad, the extra space disappears)

Can anyone enlighten me as to why this effect is occurring in one div and not the other, and how can I get rid of this ugly empty space?

```css
div {
 background-color:#f5f5f5;
 white-space:pre-line;
}
```

```html
Extra lines/space:
<div>“ąꞟë wɩȇ ŧẹ Էꭈŭℼḣȇṉ mаʏ  šё  ￨ῑẽŭ ᴑ ờἦéӓẗιơᾒꓹ wⲟɽԁṣ w∥ wỹѕ ằỉῃ ⍳ᴦ ồw‎܂‎ Ẃōɼᑯ ὸẝḟⲅ  măń ổ mèâ⍳ĝ¸ åᾕ ờӷ һ၀ŝѐ wσ w⍳∥ ῒŝê¸ ţé ẹήȗǹƈἳấȶῐ ớϝ ȑǚṭĥ․ Ᾱῇ ṫ ẗủɦ ῒṩ‚ һӷ ỉ ỏmḝŧỉῇ ṱҽṛїƀꓲ wṝ੦ṅ wį ţℎῑ ợüἤ‎٫‎ ɩ‎י‎ ťʔ Ϲμҽ⎩τӱ ɑἠ іṇμț⍳ϛ℮ꓹ ῇȱℓȅňē ӑᾐ ۵ʂṡḭօὴ꘎ ₳ḋ wė òⲥẹ ｙɥ ḣα ȶê řěὅm ό ၀ċ‎؍‎ ὄ һᾓḳ ảῆ șṗⅇà ąṣ ӯô şậw ƫ‎٫‎ ṳ ἤǫw ẵὺḙ ẽṉ ḁῂ ŝṥm ὂꞙ ƽǔṛὺéἰ‎װ‎ǻ ǒⅇӷıἧ ӱử ҫքᴑmіყ ằǹᏧ ŝ￨ϲḭեїᾑ ὃü şվᏏmιşιṇ꘎ Ḧw ꓒıⅾ τíƽ ḙᴨʔ Ẅṏʻṣ ṯọ ɓⅼӓmĕʔ Ꮃê‖ ⅇȓτӑϊ հē àḙ ḕ m๐ȓḝ ꭇṡῥռșıϸȅ һή όէһⅇᴦ¸ ῆḑ ỳ wἰ‎װ‎ ƃⅇ ɦẹⅠԁ ảčốûţẫꓲē‎٫‎ ḃꭎ ӓįℼ ṭḩ Ƅ Ƚ๐ḋ‚ ɨ ẙόứᛌᴦȅ ɬởƙῖ ꬽ һḝ ửῐţ¸  ẽḛ ὄỷ Ｉỡк ıńö  mꭈɼ‎܁‎ I поw wў ŭ Ꮷìḍ ţ꘎ I ǩἢ۵w ÿǭ wṝě ȧſŕǎɨɗ‎܁‎ Ẇһὸ wǫửΙḍπ` ⅇॽ Ꮤ‚ ḙṛôѓ‎؍‎ ɗἰ℮ȩ‎٠‎ ë wḗṝḛ  mɼӏᑯ ｏẝ ꭈọɫęm wḥⅈ č౦ηꜱřе ṯ௦ čȯꭈꭈŧ  ṥဝ àᾔḍ ꭈ ᴏ  όůӷ ƈоmmῆ ѐňѕ۰ ”
― Ⱥℓñ Ꮇӷ‎؍‎  ẝó ňԁȇṯ</div>

<br/>

And then this one is good:
<div>“Ｂȩϲạữẻ wîҽ һ ᴜπϲẖἠ m Ƅ նšӗď ïṇ ῑ ȯ ⲥṑπῧꬲʂ⍺ῖօᾕꓹ wǒӷ wἳ‖ ẳwṩ гёƫảïň ĥèіⲅ wēꓸ ổԁ ὄèг ȇ mḝẚἠṥ  měặΐŉց¸ ӑⅆ ẝо όṧḛ w wîǁ ۱ɨѕեẹή‚ ŧḧḗ ⅇñủñϲаíơṇ  էɽꓸ ꓮἣ ẖẽ ṝṵḣ ɪš¸ ȟéґѐ ỉṥ mēիȋἡ ṭḙꭇɪļ wṝṍήɠ wṫℎ ƫḧ ᴄờȓყ‎؍‎ ᑊ ţḫẻгɁ ꭇựẹ1ț ḁἡ ἱἤĵừŝỉȅ‎٫‎ ΐἥṭṑ1ꭇǡḗ ǡŉ όѓ℮òἣ‎܁‎ Ạ wիṛℯ ೦ ỗữ ɦа ţⅇ ꬵɼėᑯṑm ὄ ộɓյḙ¸ Ƚо ƫիἰὴҝ  ρậ  ỿō ẩw ẛї‎٫‎ ÿơ πw ḣὒẻ ƈḝὴѕὃґ ẵὴ ỵṯȇm ｏ ṡվｖⅡąӗ ϛỏẻⲅⅽḭᴨɡ γὂûӷ ởἡὀṛmί ậᾔ şõɫἰṯὶᾖĝ ōũꭇ ѕŭmὶƽṩớṅ‎٠‎ Ң௦w īḓ т ȟẩṗǹॽ ‎׳‎ṧ ţǭ Ꮟẫmҽʔ ℮‎װ‎ çḕȓįǹƖ ẖꬲ ã ỗȩ mᴑẹ ṓňꜱɨⅼ ṭɦấ ơѐґ‚ ȁὴ ěӳ wῒⅡ ƃḙ հḕІḋ ầςȍυήŧẳḃ‚ ƅț ẳᎥᾑ ꭇ ḕ ᴛȭᑯ‎؍‎ ⍳ օṹ´ ⅼȍộі ꞙṙ ę ûȶꓹ ꬽ éḙ ṏỷ ۵ ῒȫ  mȓô‎‎ I ὃw wу ƴ०ꭎ ḭ ꓸ I ĸǹ۵w ỹὃṹ wèɼ ẵɼắᑯ‎܁‎ ỡ wὂụⅼᾕʽե ḕᎮ ãг¸ ꬲꭈṍꓹ ¡ėậşȅ‎܂‎ Ṯḣȅꭈȇ wěⲅℯ å mřǟ ὃ ⲣɽḽêm wḥⲥ ӧᾕѓȇ тό ᴄṙ уǒữȓ ⲅℯșծ ᾕď ґὀ ๐ủ ꬽ ỿốūꭈ čòmmơ śῆƽë‎‎ ”
― Ǎĺáռ όℴⲅё‎٫‎ ꓦ ẝὃ ℮ńԁëƫ</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some characters in that particular line has an exceptionally tall `line-height`.

Manually setting the `line-height` makes them the same height.

```css
div {
 background-color:#f5f5f5;
 line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
Extra lines/space:
<div>“ąꞟë wɩȇ ŧẹ Էꭈŭℼḣȇṉ mаʏ  šё  ￨ῑẽŭ ᴑ ờἦéӓẗιơᾒꓹ wⲟɽԁṣ w∥ wỹѕ ằỉῃ ⍳ᴦ ồw‎܂‎ Ẃōɼᑯ ὸẝḟⲅ  măń ổ mèâ⍳ĝ¸ åᾕ ờӷ һ၀ŝѐ wσ w⍳∥ ῒŝê¸ ţé ẹήȗǹƈἳấȶῐ ớϝ ȑǚṭĥ․ Ᾱῇ ṫ ẗủɦ ῒṩ‚ һӷ ỉ ỏmḝŧỉῇ ṱҽṛїƀꓲ wṝ੦ṅ wį ţℎῑ ợüἤ‎٫‎ ɩ‎י‎ ťʔ Ϲμҽ⎩τӱ ɑἠ іṇμț⍳ϛ℮ꓹ ῇȱℓȅňē ӑᾐ ۵ʂṡḭօὴ꘎ ₳ḋ wė òⲥẹ ｙɥ ḣα ȶê řěὅm ό ၀ċ‎؍‎ ὄ һᾓḳ ảῆ șṗⅇà ąṣ ӯô şậw ƫ‎٫‎ ṳ ἤǫw ẵὺḙ ẽṉ ḁῂ ŝṥm ὂꞙ ƽǔṛὺéἰ‎װ‎ǻ ǒⅇӷıἧ ӱử ҫքᴑmіყ ằǹᏧ ŝ￨ϲḭեїᾑ ὃü şվᏏmιşιṇ꘎ Ḧw ꓒıⅾ τíƽ ḙᴨʔ Ẅṏʻṣ ṯọ ɓⅼӓmĕʔ Ꮃê‖ ⅇȓτӑϊ հē àḙ ḕ m๐ȓḝ ꭇṡῥռșıϸȅ һή όէһⅇᴦ¸ ῆḑ ỳ wἰ‎װ‎ ƃⅇ ɦẹⅠԁ ảčốûţẫꓲē‎٫‎ ḃꭎ ӓįℼ ṭḩ Ƅ Ƚ๐ḋ‚ ɨ ẙόứᛌᴦȅ ɬởƙῖ ꬽ һḝ ửῐţ¸  ẽḛ ὄỷ Ｉỡк ıńö  mꭈɼ‎܁‎ I поw wў ŭ Ꮷìḍ ţ꘎ I ǩἢ۵w ÿǭ wṝě ȧſŕǎɨɗ‎܁‎ Ẇһὸ wǫửΙḍπ` ⅇॽ Ꮤ‚ ḙṛôѓ‎؍‎ ɗἰ℮ȩ‎٠‎ ë wḗṝḛ  mɼӏᑯ ｏẝ ꭈọɫęm wḥⅈ č౦ηꜱřе ṯ௦ čȯꭈꭈŧ  ṥဝ àᾔḍ ꭈ ᴏ  όůӷ ƈоmmῆ ѐňѕ۰ ”
― Ⱥℓñ Ꮇӷ‎؍‎  ẝó ňԁȇṯ</div>

<br/>

And then this one is good:
<div>“Ｂȩϲạữẻ wîҽ һ ᴜπϲẖἠ m Ƅ նšӗď ïṇ ῑ ȯ ⲥṑπῧꬲʂ⍺ῖօᾕꓹ wǒӷ wἳ‖ ẳwṩ гёƫảïň ĥèіⲅ wēꓸ ổԁ ὄèг ȇ mḝẚἠṥ  měặΐŉց¸ ӑⅆ ẝо όṧḛ w wîǁ ۱ɨѕեẹή‚ ŧḧḗ ⅇñủñϲаíơṇ  էɽꓸ ꓮἣ ẖẽ ṝṵḣ ɪš¸ ȟéґѐ ỉṥ mēիȋἡ ṭḙꭇɪļ wṝṍήɠ wṫℎ ƫḧ ᴄờȓყ‎؍‎ ᑊ ţḫẻгɁ ꭇựẹ1ț ḁἡ ἱἤĵừŝỉȅ‎٫‎ ΐἥṭṑ1ꭇǡḗ ǡŉ όѓ℮òἣ‎܁‎ Ạ wիṛℯ ೦ ỗữ ɦа ţⅇ ꬵɼėᑯṑm ὄ ộɓյḙ¸ Ƚо ƫիἰὴҝ  ρậ  ỿō ẩw ẛї‎٫‎ ÿơ πw ḣὒẻ ƈḝὴѕὃґ ẵὴ ỵṯȇm ｏ ṡվｖⅡąӗ ϛỏẻⲅⅽḭᴨɡ γὂûӷ ởἡὀṛmί ậᾔ şõɫἰṯὶᾖĝ ōũꭇ ѕŭmὶƽṩớṅ‎٠‎ Ң௦w īḓ т ȟẩṗǹॽ ‎׳‎ṧ ţǭ Ꮟẫmҽʔ ℮‎װ‎ çḕȓįǹƖ ẖꬲ ã ỗȩ mᴑẹ ṓňꜱɨⅼ ṭɦấ ơѐґ‚ ȁὴ ěӳ wῒⅡ ƃḙ հḕІḋ ầςȍυήŧẳḃ‚ ƅț ẳᎥᾑ ꭇ ḕ ᴛȭᑯ‎؍‎ ⍳ օṹ´ ⅼȍộі ꞙṙ ę ûȶꓹ ꬽ éḙ ṏỷ ۵ ῒȫ  mȓô‎‎ I ὃw wу ƴ०ꭎ ḭ ꓸ I ĸǹ۵w ỹὃṹ wèɼ ẵɼắᑯ‎܁‎ ỡ wὂụⅼᾕʽե ḕᎮ ãг¸ ꬲꭈṍꓹ ¡ėậşȅ‎܂‎ Ṯḣȅꭈȇ wěⲅℯ å mřǟ ὃ ⲣɽḽêm wḥⲥ ӧᾕѓȇ тό ᴄṙ уǒữȓ ⲅℯșծ ᾕď ґὀ ๐ủ ꬽ ỿốūꭈ čòmmơ śῆƽë‎‎ ”
― Ǎĺáռ όℴⲅё‎٫‎ ꓦ ẝὃ ℮ńԁëƫ</div>
```